# shuffle numbers in an Arraylist

Tags: arraylist

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void kocokAjah (View view) {

```
    TextView textViewCard = findViewById(R.id.textViewCard);
    relativeLayoutGone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textViewCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    int MyFirstNumber = Integer.parseInt(editNumBegin.getText().toString());
    int MyLastNumber = Integer.parseInt(editNumEnd.getText().toString());

    ArrayList<String> kocok = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = MyFirstNumber; i <= MyLastNumber; i++) {

        kocok.add(Integer.toString(i));
        Collections.shuffle(kocok);

        textViewCard.setText((CharSequence) kocok);

    }
}
```

}

This is my code to shuffle numbers in an ArrayList thean sen it to a TextView. 
but whenever i the code is executed the app crash.

log :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.theinmark.fernando.kocoktestmainactivity, PID: 6506
                                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                                                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
                                                                                                at com.theinmark.fernando.kocoktestmainactivity.MainActivity.kocokAjah(MainActivity.java:91)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015) 
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
01-27 16:21:27.520 6506-6506/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6506 SIG: 9

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of that long error message you will find this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

The problem is an ArrayList (regadless of what it contains) is not a CharSequence. If I remember correctly, Strings implement CharSequence, so maybe you'll want to build a string instead of a list of strings.

The quick and dirty way is to just "add" the strings together.

```
String kocok="";
for(...) {
    kocok += Integer.toString(i);
}
```

The better way is to use a StringBuilder. But it's only really necessary if you add a lot of strings together.

Also note that you are calling `setText` on the text view inside the loop. You would typically to that after the loop.

If you want to shuffle the numbers before appending them to the string, I would recommend that you first add the numbers to an array, then after that loop shuffle once, then another loop to convert to a string, then after that set text on text field.

```
/* Pseudocode.*/
for (int i; ...) {
    array.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(array);
String str=""
for (int i: array) { /* for each int i in array. */
    str+=i;
}
textview.setText(str);
```

Comment: SO amazing that i have this answer. awesome, thank God, wow. Thank a lot to you @Brainstorm

Comment: i had tried the solution you gave. Another issue is,  "how to call the shuffled list of numbers without repeating?". .                                                                                              
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = MyFirstNumber; i <= MyLastNumber; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        shuffle(numbers);
        int numbersSize = numbers.size();
        int numbersIndex = 0;
        textViewCard.setText(Integer.toString(numbers.get(order++)));
        System.out.println(numbers);